# Git pushes to remote repo but will not deploy code the live website folder

Tags: git, ssh

I am trying to use git to deploy a website to my live server for the the first time, I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qIK8ZC9BnU). When I push to the live site everything is uploaded to the /repos/my-website.git folder but the folder where I want view the website remains empty.

I think there is a problem with --work-tree in the post-receive?

In this folder

```
/var/chroot/home/content/26/12629726/repos/my-website.git/hooks
```

I set up post-recieve with vim

```
vi post-receive

#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/chroot/content/26/12629726/html/OTHER-WEBSITES/my-website --git-dir=/var/chroot/content/26/12629726/repos/my-website.git checkout -f
```

Set up remote called "live"

```
git remote -v
live    ssh://user@my-website.com/~/repos/my-website.git/ (fetch)
live    ssh://user@my-website.com/~/repos/my-website.git/ (push)
origin  https://github.com/git-user/mywebsite.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/git-user/mywebsite.git (push)
```

When I push everything goes to the git folder
    git push live master

```
Warning: Permanently added 'my-website.com,222.111.222.1' (DSA) to the list of known hosts.
Password:
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 395 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://user@my-website.com/~/repos/my-website.git/
   8fc9229..bb1042f  master -> master
```

This folder does not recieve the files

```
/var/chroot/content/26/12629726/html/OTHER-WEBSITES/my-website
```

Thanks

Comment: Make sure the hook has execute permission set.  Add a line to the hook to print something, so that you can see, on the client, whether the hook is run. (Messages printed by the hook are copied to the client; on the client, they get prefixed with `remote: `.)

Comment: Did you mean "chmod +x post-receive". How exactly would I add a line to print something? This is my first time using vim and SSH. Thanks

Comment: Yes, assuming a Unix/Linux-like system (I have no idea how this works on Windows, which I do my best to avoid :-) ).  To print things in a shell or bash script, simply "echo" it: `echo hello world` for instance.

Comment: I set up the shell script as you recommended, where can I see if it is printing? I pushed another commit to the remote and and checked the git log but did not see anything.

Comment: You would see it on your client machine when you did the push.  Since you saw nothing, that implies that the script still is not running.  Figuring out *why* is tricky.  If the server is a Linux box, check for security settings (SELinux, for instance).  I fussed with one of those on and off for a week, some years ago, before giving up and putting the server on a non-SELinux machine instead.

Comment: I tried a different angle and cloned the repo into `html/OTHER-WEBSITES/my-website` so now I can at least update using `git pull`. I then tried a different bash/shell script `#!/bin/sh
cd ~/html/OTHER-WEBSITES/my-website || exit
unset GIT_DIR
git pull origin master

exec git-update-server-info`  in `~/repos/my-website.git/hooks/post-update` but that did not work either.